# Websphere 7 with UPS Web service integration

Tags: java, ssl, https, ups

I’m trying to integrate with my application with UPS Web service in `Websphere 7`. But  it gives the certificate chaining error. How can I fix this?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US is not trusted; internal cause is: 
    java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:25)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:499)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:483)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:48)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:426)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.lb.a(lb.java:194)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.s(kb.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.kb.a(kb.java:128)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:516)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.h(SSLSocketImpl.java:400)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.a(SSLSocketImpl.java:787)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:640)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:143)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:36)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1026)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set up UPS web service call works properly with WCS server, we need to install the security certificate for UPS in WCS server.
Start WCS serve.
Start Administration Console by right clicking the server and selecting “Run Administration Console” from Administration Context menu.
From the Administration console window, expend Security and select “SSL certificate and key management”.
Click on “SSL configuration”.
Select “NodeDefaultSSLSetting”.
Click on “Key stores and certificates”.
Select “NodeDefaultTrustStore”.
Click on “Signer certificates”.
Click on “Retrieve from port” button.
Fill in “wwwcie.ups.com” as host and “443” as port.
Click on “OK” button and save.
Restart the WCS server.
```